# jQuery.ui Datepicker - Styling Days of the week

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery.ui Datepicker to try to style a particular date as selected. The date is being returned via ajax request. When I use the beforeShowDay, it hides my inline form. I am looking for a function that will handle the styling in an inline calendar.

What's the correct approach for this.

Thanks

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/?ACT=103',
        success: function(json)
        {

            var SelectedDates = {};

            SelectedDates[new Date(json[0].mealDate)] = new Date(json[0].mealDate);
            console.log(SelectedDates);

            $('#z').datepicker({
                inline: true,
                altField: '#d',
                minDate: 0,
                beforeShowDay: function(date)
                {
                    var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
                    if (Highlight) {
                        return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
                    }
                    else {
                        return [true, '', ''];
                    }
                }

            });

        },
        error:function()
        {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: .addClass('Highlighted') ??

Comment: this should be the case with the returned array
`A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
[0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
[1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
[2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.`